# How to run Django test as specific user

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-testing

I am new to Django and need to write some API tests. The views that I am testing have the decorator

```
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAdminUser,))
```

I am using TestCase and Client. Would Admin already be "logged in" for the test or do I need to somehow set the user to Admin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an instance of `django.test.Client` and then to use [`Client.login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login) so that specifying the desired user.

Be sure the user to log is admin ofc.

```
  from django.test import Client
  client = Client()
  client.login(username="adminusername", password="adminpassword")
  # client.get(...)
  # client.post(...)
```